# Make XAML control with WebView full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

**Ultimate Goal**

When a user clicks the `Expand` button, I want the `WebContainerControl` to be full screen, be focused, not allow scrolling in the `ScrollViewer`, and overlap the title grid (with the back button, page title, etc.)

Basically, it should be like clicking on a photo in a nice photo viewing app. Exapnd to full screen, have an `X` button in the top right corner and when you click it, it goes back to the regular view.

**Problem**

Since it's a `WebView`, I can't simply pass the view to a popup (It gives me an invalid args exception since the current browsing session can't be passed by reference... they logged in on a site, so it would be insecure I assume)

I have a XAML control with a webview in it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.WebContainerControl">
    <Grid x:Name="grdWebContainer">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Click="btnExpandView_Click"/>
            <WebView x:Name="wvSite"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is an example view it would be loaded into:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Title Grid -->
    <Grid x:Name="grdTitleBar" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="App Title"/>
    </Grid>
    <!-- Web Views -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <controls:WebContainerControl x:Name="First Site"/>
                <controls:WebContainerControl x:Name="Second Site"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**What I have so far**

So far, when they press the `Expand` button, it makes the control full screen (using `Current.Window.Bounds`)
Then, I pass the event that the button is pressed to the main view:

```
private void OnAccount_Expanded(object sender, ExpandedEventArgs args) {
    // Expanded button is pressed and control is made full screen
    if (args.IsExpanded) {
        // Hide titlebar
        grdMain.RowDefinitions[0].Height = GridLength.Auto;
        grdTitleBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else {
        // show titlebar again
        GridLength gl = new GridLength(140);
        grdMain.RowDefinitions[0].Height = gl;
        grdTitleBar.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

**The Question**

Right now, it makes it full screen, but I can still scroll. Any idea how to set the `ScrollViewer` to horizontally center on the control? If anyone has a better idea on how to achieve my `Ultimate Goal`, you would make me one happy camper! (Remember, it won't allow me to pass my control around, only manipulate it)

Comment: Question: after doing full screen you don't want to allow scroll you mean?@LeviFuller

Answer (score 0):

If I understand  well, Put name on you Scroll Viewer

```
<ScrollViewer Name="uiScroll" >
        ............
 </ScrollViewer >
```

When you doing full screen set visibility of you scrollBar

```
  uiScroll.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

Comment: Say the user has four WebControlContainers on the screen and his screen is centered in the middle (between two controls), I still need to center the `ScrollViewer` so that when the control is made full screen, it's not showing the bottom one they expanded still at the bottom of the screen. That would just lock it in place, correct?

Comment: You need center scroll viewer  or controls inside scroll viewer?@LeviFuller

Comment: The control in the `ScrollViewer`. I do appreciate the help, by the way.